# Install root certificate authority on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssl, certificate

First off I am not sure whether I have the correct terminology. What I mean by certificate authority is a verified certificate distributor such that if I goto a website in my Browser that is HTTPS (with an SSL certificate) it doesn't give a warning that it might be unsafe.

There is two things I need to do here.

I have a Windows XP machine and a Linux Mint (Ubuntu 14 base) machine. The Windows XP machine has a certificate authority installed such that it authorizes use of certificates it distributes so that I don't get any warnings in my browsers. I need to extract this from the Windows XP machine

Second, I need to "install" this onto my Ubuntu machine such that it when I visit a website via any browser on my Ubuntu machine that has a certificate issued by the CA, that I don't get  a warning/have to add an exception.

I hope I have asked the question properly - please say if you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Save the CA certificate to a file, in PEM format (the text format with `BEGIN CERTIFICATE` headers). If you have it in binary (DER) format, use `openssl x509 -inform der` to convert.

Make sure the file name has a `.crt` extension. Copy it to the `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` directory and run `update-ca-certificates`. Finally, restart your web browser.

---

While both Chromium and Firefox have their own CA databases, on Linux they *should* pick up all certificates from the system-wide store nevertheless. But if they don't, you can use `certtool` to fix that, by installing the CA into your personal browser profile. (Both browsers use NSS format databases.)

For [Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxCertManagement), the certificate database is always `sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb`:

```
certutil -d "sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb" -A -i ca.pem -n "My CA" -t "C,,"
```

For Firefox, use the profile directory instead; e.g. `$HOME/.mozilla/firefox/ov6jazas.default` (without the "sql:" prefix).